# Let $\theta$ be a root of $p(x)=x^3+9x+6$, find the inverse of $1+\theta$ in $\mathbb{Q(\theta)}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

Let $\theta$ be a root of $p(x)=x^3+9x+6$, find the inverse of $1+\theta$ in $\mathbb{Q(\theta)}$.

So problems like this really annoy me but I did crappy on the last homework after making a lot of arithmetic mistakes so I want to run everything by you guys. This one isn't actually for homework it's just a suggested practice problem but okay lets go!!!

So I'm not sure if the method I used to do this was standard or not, I don't remember my professor showing me, but what I did first was used the canonical euclidean algorithm in $\mathbb{Q[x]}$ and wrote:

$x^3+9x+6$

$=(1+x)(x^2-x+10-\frac{4}{x+1})$

$=(1+x)(x^2-x+10)-4$

the reduced modulo  the minimal polynomial of $\theta$ i.e. $x^3+9x+6$ and so

$4=(1+x)(x^2-x+10)$

$\rightarrow$

$1= \frac{1}{4}(1+x)(x^2-x+10)$ and sooo ah $(\theta^2-\theta+10)\frac{1}{4}$ is what I believe is the inverse of $(1+\theta)$ in the quotient field... Like i said I hate these problems but ehh is this correct? On a lighter note it's finally getting cool enough for me to go on proper runs here and so that's pretty bomb!

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193199/computing-the-inverse-of-an-element-in-mathbbq-theta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct: it takes only $1$ step (division $f\div g)\,$ in the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242) to invert a *linear* polynomial $\,g\,$ since  $ f =  q\,g + c \,\Rightarrow\, \bmod f\!:\ q\,g\equiv -c\,\Rightarrow\, 1/g \equiv -q/c,\,$ just as you calculated (the remainder $\,c\,$ is a *constant* since it must have degree $< 1 \!=\! \deg g\,$ by the division algorithm, and $\,c\neq 0\,$ when $\,g\nmid f).$

---

Generally it's easier to use said *augmented-matrix form*  of the extended Euclidean algorithm, e.g. below we compute $\,1/g \pmod{\!f} = 1/(x^2\!+\!1) \pmod{\!x^3\!+\!2x\!+\!1}\,$ over $\,\Bbb Z_3,\,$  from [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/124307/242)

$\begin{eqnarray}
[\![1]\!]&&  &&f = x^3\!+2x+1 &\!\!=&\, \left<\,\color{#c00}1,\,\color{#0a0}0\,\right>\quad\ \ \, {\rm i.e.}\ \qquad\!\:\! f\, =\ \color{#c00}1\cdot f\, +\, \color{#0a0}0\cdot g\\
[\![2]\!]&&  &&\qquad\ \,  g =x^2\!+1 &\!\!=&\, \left<\,\color{#c00}0,\,\color{#0a0}1\,\right>\quad\ \ \,{\rm i.e.}\ \qquad g\, =\ \color{#c00}0\cdot f\, +\, \color{#0a0}1\cdot g\\
[\![3]\!]&=&[\![1]\!]-x[\![2]\!]\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! &&\qquad\qquad\ \ x+1 \,&\!\!=&\, \left<\,\color{#c00}1,\,\color{#0a0}{-x}\,\right>\ \ \ \:\!{\rm i.e.}\quad\! x\!+\!1\, =\, \color{#c00}1\cdot f\,\color{#0c0}{-\,x}\cdot g\\
[\![4]\!]&=&[\![2]\!]+(1\!-\!x)[\![3]\!]\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! &&\qquad\qquad\qquad\ 2 \,&\!\!=&\, \left<\,\color{#c00}{1\!-\!x},\,\ \color{#0a0}{1\!-\!x+x^2}\,\right>\\
\end{eqnarray}$

Hence the prior line implies: $\ \ 2\  =\  (\color{#c00}{1\!-\!x})f + (\color{#0a0}{1\!-\!x\!+\!x^2})g $

Thus in $\,\Bbb Z_3[x] \bmod f\!:\,\  {-}1\equiv 2 \equiv (\color{#0a0}{1\!-\!x\!+\!x^2})g\ \Rightarrow\ \bbox[6px,border:1px solid red]{g^{-1}\equiv\, {-}(\color{#0a0}{1\!-\!x\!+\!x^2})}$

---

**Remark** $ $ Just as for [the integer case](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242), we can omit one of the above Bezout coef's,  which amounts to working with modular polynomial fractions, e.g. [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2368266/242) where I show how to view an algorithm of Joe Silverman as a simple special case (analogous to the binary extended Euclidean algorithm done using mediant arithmetic and cancellation of $2)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$     \left(   \frac{  x^{2}  -  x  + 10 }{ 4 }  \right)   $$

==================================================

$$  \left(   x^{3}  + 9 x  + 6 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x  + 1 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{3}  + 9 x  + 6 \right)  =  \left(   x  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  + 10 \right) } +  \left( -4  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x  + 1 \right)  =  \left( -4  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  -  x  - 1 }{ 4 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  + 10 \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  + 10 \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  -  x  - 1 }{ 4 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  -  x^{3}  - 9 x  - 6 }{ 4 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  -  x  - 1 }{ 4 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{3}  + 9 x  + 6 \right)  \left( \frac{ 1}{4 } \right)  -  \left(   x  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{  x^{2}  -  x  + 10 }{ 4 }  \right)  =  \left( -1  \right)  $$

==============================================================

To display the notation used above: here is a gcd for integers, with the continued fraction displayed in the traditional sideways manner:

$$  \gcd( 54321, 12345 ) = ???    $$

$$ \frac{ 54321 }{ 12345 } = 4 +  \frac{ 4941 }{ 12345 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 12345 }{ 4941 } = 2 +  \frac{ 2463 }{ 4941 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 4941 }{ 2463 } = 2 +  \frac{ 15 }{ 2463 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 2463 }{ 15 } = 164 +  \frac{ 3 }{ 15 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 15 }{ 3 } = 5 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 3 } $$ 
 Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 & & 4 & & 2 & & 2 & & 164 & & 5 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 4 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 9 }{ 2 }   & &   \frac{ 22 }{ 5 }   & &   \frac{ 3617 }{ 822 }   & &   \frac{ 18107 }{ 4115 }  
 \end{array}
 $$ 
 $$  $$ 
 $$ 18107 \cdot 822 - 4115 \cdot 3617 = -1 $$

$$  \gcd( 54321, 12345 ) = 3  $$
 $$ 54321 \cdot 822 - 12345 \cdot 3617 = -3 $$

Comment: Your answer would benefit from some kind of explanation of how to decipher it. What are $\dfrac{0}{1}$ and $\dfrac{1}{0}$? What does $\implies\implies$ mean? What is the big string of = signs for? Why are some terms in pink? I'm baffled!

Comment: @CliveNewstead  I like to do the "extended" part of the Extended Euclidean Algorithm as a simple continued fraction. It also works for polynomials with rational coefficients. The "convergents" for the continued fraction begin with two fake convergents, namely the "fractions" you indicate. Oh, note that I answered a similar question by the same OP yesterday, and he pretty clear was comfortable with the notation. Whether he truly understood is another matter. I have always liked the fact that we can get away with continued fractions with polynomials  as numerators and denominators.

Comment: @CliveNewstead I added an ordinary extended gcd calculation, to show the notation in a more familiar light.

Comment: @WillJagy that (good) answer is not only for OP but for other people who have interests in your answer. I do not know what $\implies\implies$ means too.