# Finding the $\gcd$ of $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ in field $\mathbb{F}$

Tags: finite-fields, euclidean-algorithm

I'm trying to find the $\gcd$ of $a(x) = x^4 + 2x^3+x^2+4x+2$ and $b(x)=x^2+3x+1$ over $\mathbb{F_5}$. I've already tried Euclid's algorithm:

$x^4 + 2x^3+x^2+4x+2 = x^2(x^2+3x+1) - x^3+4x+2$. Now I should express $b(x)$ in terms of the remainder $-x^3+4x+2$, but I'm not sure how to do this since $\deg(b(x)) < 3$. Did I do something incorrectly? How do I find the $\gcd$?

Comment: You didn't complete the (Euclidean) division - doing so yields a remainder of *smaller* degree than the divisor.

Answer (score 1):

It is perhaps easier just to factorize the polynomials over $\Bbb F_5$ instead of using the Euclidean algorithm:

$$
x^4+2x^3+x^2+4x+2=(x^3+3x^2+4x+3)(x+4)
$$

$$
x^2+3x+1=(x+4)^2
$$

For this is enough to look for roots. The second polynomial obviously has $x=-4=1$ as a double root. So what about the first polynomial? Clearly it has also a root $1$. What about the cubic polynomial left?

So you see that $gcd(a(x),b(x))=x+4$ over $\Bbb F_5$. Note that the gcd is $1$ over $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Thanks! One more question: assume I want to find the coefficients $\lambda (x), \mu (x)$ such that $\gcd(a(x),b(x)) = \lambda (x) a(x) + \mu (x) b(x)$. Can I find them using your method?

Comment: @Zachary Use the Extended Euclidean algorithm, e.g. [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2959891/242).