# Multiplicative inverse of $n+1$ modulo $n^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

> Find the multiplicative inverse of $n+1$ modulo $n^2$ , where $n$ is any integer greater than $1$

We have to find $z$ such that $(n+1)z=1\pmod{n^2}$
$$
n^2-k(n+1)=n^2-kn-k=1\implies n^2-kn-(k+1)=0\\
\implies n=k+1\text{ or }-1\implies \boxed{k=n-1}\\
n^2-(n-1)(n+1)=1
$$
For $a>b$ using Euclid's algorithm we can conclude that $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a-b,b)$.
$$
\gcd(n^2,n+1)=\gcd(n^2-(n+1),n+1)=\gcd(n^2-2(n+1),n+1)=\cdots=\gcd(n^2-(n-1)(n+1),n+1)=\gcd(1,n+1)=1
$$
$\implies $ inverse exists

But how do I proceed further? Can we follow the same steps for a particular integer ?

For example if it were to find $27$ modulo $4$ then

$27b=1\pmod4$ and $\gcd(27,4=1)\implies $ inverse exists

$$
27=6\times 4+3\\
4=1\times 3+3
$$
$$
3=27-6\times 4\\
1=4-1\times 3
$$
$$
1-4-1\times 3=4-1(27-6\times 4)=4-1\times 27+6\times 4\\
1=7\times 4-1\times 27\\
27\times -1=-7\times 4+1\\
27\times -1=1\pmod 4
$$

Comment: Divide $n^2=(n+1)(n-1)+1$. Therefore $(n+1)(-n+1)=n^2(-1)+1$. In general, you do Euclid's algorithm to produce [Bezout's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#B%C3%A9zout's_identity_and_extended_GCD_algorithm). This gives you polynomials $a,b$ such that $a(n)n^2+b(n)(n+1)=1$. Then the inverse of $n+1$ modulo $n^2$ is $b(n)$.

Comment: The inverse is $1-n$.

Comment: As explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3224776/242) in the 1st linked dupe (see "nilpotents")  $\ $ 
$$\bmod \color{#c00}{n^2}\!:\,\ \dfrac{1}{1+n} = \dfrac{1-n}{1-\color{#c00}{n^2}\!} = \dfrac{1-n}{1-\color{#c00}0}\qquad\qquad$$  See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3225783/242) in the 2nd dupe for another example of inverting a **unit + nilpotent**.

Comment: @BillDubuque Is the recursive substitution method I used a special case of those results?

Comment: **Or** use Hensel's Lemma: $\bmod n\!:\ 1 \equiv (n\!+\!1)x\equiv x\iff x =  1\! +\! kn,\,$ so 
$\bmod n^2\!:\ 1 \equiv (1\!+\!n)x\equiv (1\!+\!n)(1\!+\!kn) \equiv 1 + n(1\!+\!k) \iff k\equiv -1\pmod{n}$ $\iff x\equiv 1-n\pmod{n^2}\ \ $

Comment: **Or** use a couple steps of the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2959891/242) to get the Bezout identity for $\,\gcd(n^2,1+n)=1,\,$ viz. $\, n^2 + (1-n)(1+n) = 1\ \ $

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by the "recursive subst, method". Please elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

Since $(n+1)(n-1) \equiv (-1) \pmod{n^2}$ and since $(-1)^2 \equiv 1\pmod{n^2}$, you have that

$[(n+1)(n-1)]^2 \equiv 1\pmod{n^2}.$

Therefore, the inverse of $(n+1)$ is $[(n+1)(n-1)^2]$.

This inverse simplifies to $(-1)(n-1) = (1 - n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Given $(n+1)z=1 \mod n^2$ we see that $$z=1-zn=1-(1-zn)n=1-n-zn^2=1-n\mod n^2$$