# Multiplicative inverse in the extended euclidean algorithm

Tags: abstract-algebra, euclidean-algorithm

I am trying to use the extended euclidean algorithm to find the multiplicative inverse of 02 (in hexadecimal) and $x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$ over GF($2^8$). I tried to apply the algorithm between $x^2$ and the given polynomial. Dividing the polynomial by $x^2$ gives a quotient of $x^6+x^2+x$ and a remainder of $x+1$ so I tried dividing $x^2$ by the remainder and they are co-prime so the GCD is 1 and according to the algorithm I am using the inverse is the inverse of x+1 modulo $x^2$, for this do I need to apply the extended algorithm again, or how do I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

An easy *general* way is the *forward* extended Euclidean algorithm, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2959891/242) for a worked example of this method (this is *easier* and *less error-prone* than the common "backward" form).

However, in this case it's a bit easier to use an  [optimization: (inverse $\rm\color{#c00}{reciprocity}$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242), which computes $\,b \equiv {\large \frac{1}{\color{#c00}{x^2}}}\bmod \color{#c00}f\,$ from $\,a\equiv {\large \frac{1}{\color{#c00}f}} \bmod \color{#c00}{x^2}$ (easier), viz.

suppose $\,af+b\:\!x^2 = 1\,$ and $\,f \equiv 1+x \pmod{\!x^2},\,$ as for your $f = 1+x+x^3+x^4+x^8$.

$\!\!\bmod \color{#0a0}{x^2}\!:\ 1 \equiv af \equiv a(1+x) \iff  a \equiv \dfrac{1}{1+x} \equiv \dfrac{\!\!1-x}{1-\color{#0a0}{x^2}} \equiv 1-x$

Thus $\,b = \dfrac{1-af}{x^2},\,$ which yields $\,b =1-x+x^3-x^6+x^7$ for your  $f$.

**Note** $ $ The above method of computing $\,1/(1\!+\!x)\bmod x^2\,$ is not ad-hoc. Rather it is a special case of the  [method of simpler multiples](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3224776/242) (a nilpotent analog of *rationalizing the denominator*).

Comment: is there another method

Comment: @Sergio Yes, the (forward) extended Euclidean algorithm (augmented matrix form) in the first link, which is the same as the common "backward" method you are applying except it keeps track of each remainders value as a linear combination of the gcd arguments by propagating them *foward* from the start (vs. *backward* from the end via back-substitution - which is more error prone).